# pgfplots, using sprintf in clickable library

Tags: pgfplots

I am using pgfplots in combination with the clickable library. Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

% important packages
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [% options
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$x$},
    clickable coords = {exact coords: <br/> (xy)}, % activates a snap-to-nearest feature
    annot/snap dist=10,
    clickable coords size = {10,5}, % size in characters for the snapping pop ups
    annot/popup size generic = {20,10}, % size in characters  for the rest
    ]
\addplot
    [% options
    only marks, % do not connect data points
    ] 
    coordinates 
    {
    (0,0)
    (2,2)
    (5,5)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result can be seen here

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1833443/clickable-Problem/my_LaTeX_File.pdf

If you click near the data points then you will get a message like this:

```
exact coords:
(x,y)
```

If you click anywhere else you just get:

```
(x,y)
```

Here's a screenshot of the first case:
[image: Screenshot]

In the pgfplots documentation in chapter 5.1.3 there is also mentioned that you can use the sprintf syntax to customize the formatting. Example:

```
/pgfplots/annot/point format={sprintf-format} (initially (%.1f,%.1f))
```

[image: documentation]

But I do not understand how I can use the

```
%
```

and

```
\n
```

within the normal LaTeX code.

**Does anyone have an example how to use the line break symbol (\n) and the variable placeholder symbol (%) in the context of the clickable library?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clickable lib has extra support for the control sequences or chars `"`, `\#`, `|`, `\"`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\\`, `\%`.

It should work out-of-the-box if you place these special escapes into the argument.

And it used to work, at least together with `pdflatex`.

Note that the manual appears to be incorrect: the initial values of these keys are

```
annot/point format/.initial={(\%.1f, \%.1f)},
annot/point format 3d/.initial={(\%.1f, \%.1f, \%.1f)},
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try it again. Very cool that the author himself answers me here.